# sequence that diverges to infinity multiplied by a sequence that converges to $-1$?

Tags: calculus

Lets take two sequences:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n \to \infty$$
And 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n \to -1$$
What can you tell me about 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nb_n \to ?$$

Comment: I edited your title; just so you know, sequences cannot converge to $\infty$. They diverge to $\infty$

Comment: @graydad Oh i see thanks

Comment: It's not [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), so you can simply conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $b_n \to -1$, we must have for some $N$, $b_n < 0$ for $n > N$. Similarly, since $a_n \to \infty$ we must have that for some $N'$, $a_n > 0$ for $n>n'$.
So, for $n>\max{N,N'}$ we must have that $a_n b_n < 0$.
We also have that, since $b_n \not= 0$ for such $n$ that $a_n b_n \to -\infty$.

Edit: to make the argument more formal, for each $\epsilon > 0$, take $N''$ to be the integer such that for $n > N''$, $|b_n - 1| < \epsilon$. Then if $M = \max\{N, N', N''\}$, then for all $n > M$ we have that $a_n b_n < a_n b_M$ and $a_n b_M \to -\infty$ since b_M is a negative constant. Hence $a_n b_n \to -\infty$.

Comment: there is something missing. when $b_n<0$ and $a_n\to\infty$, you can have $b_n = -1/n^2$ and $a_n =  n$, so that the limit of the product is $0$.

Comment: But if $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ then we don't have that $b_n \to -1$.

Comment: yes. But there is still something missing in your answer. I read: "So, for n>max N,N′   we must have that $a_n b_n <0$ . We also have that, since $b_n ≠0$  for such $n$  that $a_n b_n →−∞ .$".

Comment: Okay, edited to make it more clear.

Comment: it may be good. I still find my answer clearer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $A>0$. Consider $N$ big enough, so that for $n>N$
$$
b_n <- \frac 12
\\
a_n > 2A.
$$

Comment: I didnt understand how to work with this example :D

Comment: I can't see, how $b_n$ can be bigger than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow c} a_n*b_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow c} a_n\lim_{n\rightarrow c} b_n$$

Given 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n=\infty$$
and

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n=-1$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n*b_n=-1*\infty=-\infty.$$

Comment: This approach requires that both limits exist

Comment: It does not, unless the final product is indeterminate ($0*\infty,\dfrac{0}{0},etc$)

Comment: @MathNoob: Youre right, but you should correct your notation to $n\to\infty$, instead of $x\to c$ or $x\to\infty$...